# Ruby script restart itself after being killed with signal 137

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I'm doing a test on an amazon microinstance where I'm runing a web server and a crawler written in Ruby (using Mechanize gem) on the same machine. The purpose of the test is to find the maximum load a microinstance server can handle (school project). However the system (Ubuntu) keeps killing my Ruby crawler with 137 when memory has reached its maximum. The memory gets full because of the webserver (mysql more precisely), not because of the crawler and it still kills the crawler. Therefore I would like to be able to prevent the system to kill my ruby script or to restart the script automatically when killed. Is that possible? I don't want to use different instance since I'm using free tier (and I don't want to pay for it).

I found a solution here on stackoverflow:
[How do I ensure a process is running, even if it kills itself? (it needs to be restarted then)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627440/how-do-i-ensure-a-process-is-running-even-if-it-kills-itself-it-needs-to-be-r)

but from what I understand there, it will keep starting the script over and over without even the need of being killed. Am I right? (I can't comment on the original question because of lack of reputation) I understand it's a bad workaround but I have no idea how to solve it differently.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: the best way would be to use a monitoring service like bluepill to handle the restarting, but if everything gets killed by an out of memory error this will fail likewise. i would try using a cronjob that checks if the script is still running, starting it new if it's not. the cron deamon is hopefully protected from being killed.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at it. I'm just afraid it won't work since the process is called "ruby" because my starting command is `ruby test.rb` (and for unknown reason I can't make it work as a standalone script)

Comment: does your script have a shebang? `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` does it have executable rights? `chmod u+x`

Comment: it does have both. After I run only "test.rb" I'm getting: `Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report`